# Restore Oracle database on a different Pc

Tags: oracle11g, database-backups, database-restore

I have been using Oracle XE and has a backup of the app folder containing all the database Objects I need to restore this database on to a different Machine Bu I cant find a way to do this.

I have tried to reinstall Oracle on the new PC and replace the app folder of the current Installation but the database and restarting the services but I am getting the error that the network adapter does not know the sid given.

How can I do this and is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace only the `oradata` folder.